# Remove pageName variable of a Omniture instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm using two instances of `AppMeasurement` for send request,

1. with `pageName` variable and
2. without the `pageName` variable.

In my app for all pages, inside the `viewDidAppear` method, I send a **omniture** request with `pageName` variable like follow,

```
AppMeasurement * s1;    
s1 = [appDelegate getAppMeasurementNormalInstance];
s1.pageName = @"Main Page";
s1.products = productsVariable;
s1.events = @"event6";
[s1 track];
```

When I click on a button of that page, I send a **omniture** request without `pageName` variable like follow (After above request sent),

```
AppMeasurement * s2;    
s2 = [appDelegate getAppMeasurementClickthroughInstance];

s2.products = productsVariable;
s2.events=@"event1";
[s2 track];
```

But the issue is when I send the **omniture** request by `s2` instance, it's containing the `pageName` variable which is equal to the s1 instance's `pageName` variable like follow,

```
ndh=1
t=9/4/2012 18:14:56 3 -330
vid= 0E5DA96B0F97304E870BB6C123456789
ce=UTF-8
pageName=Main Page
cc=USD
events=event1
products=;;;;;evar3=266801;evar5=12345;evar15=;evar36=1;
s=768x1024
c=24
AQE=1
```

So I want to send that request without the `pageName` variable.

I tried `s2.pageName = nil;`. But after that **omniture** generates a value for the pageName variable.

So need someone's help for resolve this please. 
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Custom link tracking image requests ALWAYS strip the pageName variable server-side. I'm not too familiar with the code syntax, but based on the patterns above it would look something like this:

```
AppMeasurement * s2;    
s2 = [appDelegate getAppMeasurementClickthroughInstance];

s2.products = productsVariable;
s2.events=@"event1";
s2.linkTrackVars=@"productsVariable,events";
s2.linkTrackEvents=@"event1";
[s2 trackLink];
```

Additional information on link tracking can be found here:
http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/whitepapers/link_tracking/index.html#Link+Tracking+-+File+Downloads,+Exit+Links,+and+Custom+Links

Comment: Also note that no matter what, you will always see the pageName variable in the debugger (even on link tracking image requests). Since they are stripped server-side, this is intentional.

Comment: Also make sure you use clearVars() or use the TemporaryOverride option of the trackLink method as described in the manual linked above. Otherwise, the event will carry over to the next image request.